# SQL to Zend_Db_Table

Tags: mysql, sql, zend-db, zend-db-table

I'm trying to convert a SQL to Zend_Db_Table

```
SELECT c1.* FROM beneficios c1
left join beneficios c2 on c1.document_id = c2.document_id and c1.versao <       c2.versao
where c1.id_projeto = 8 and c2.document_id is null order by ordem ASC;
```

I have a method inside a zend db table class

```
$info = $this->info();
    $select = $this->select()
         ->from(array('c1' => $info['name']))
         ->joinLeft(array('c2' => $info['name']),
                'c1.document_id = c2.document_id and c1.versao < c2.versao')
            ->where('c2.document_id is null')
            ->where('c1.id_projeto = ?', $id_projeto)
            ->order('ordem ASC');

    return $this->fetchAll($select);
```

I get the following error

```
Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'ordem' in order clause is ambiguous
```

if I remove order

```
Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound
```

What's the correct way to convert that SQL?

If anyone could help me, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of $this->select() use $this->getAdapter()->select().  Also you can specify that you don't want any of the columns from table c2 by passing an empty array to the joinLeft function:

```
$info = $this->info();
    $select = $this->getAdapter->select()
         ->from(array('c1' => $info['name']))
         ->joinLeft(array('c2' => $info['name']),
                'c1.document_id = c2.document_id and c1.versao < c2.versao', array())
            ->where('c2.document_id is null')
            ->where('c1.id_projeto = ?', $id_projeto)
            ->order('ordem ASC');

return $this->fetchAll($select);
```

Comment: @Brian Fisher Hi, it returns me Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: For debugging purposes can you hardcode the $info['name'] to 'beneficios' and the $id_projeto to 8 and let us know what happens.

Comment: I replaced it but still returns me the same error, I printed the SQL: "SELECT `c1`.* FROM `beneficios` AS `c1` LEFT JOIN `beneficios` AS `c2` ON c1.document_id = c2.document_id and c1.versao < c2.versao WHERE (c2.document_id is null) AND (c1.id_projeto = 8) ORDER BY `ordem` ASC"

Comment: It shouldn't work, as column "ordem" is in both aliases tables (which is one table). So he just needs to put alias name in order. See anwser of @Matthew

Answer (score 1):

It's just as it says: "Column 'ordem' in order clause is ambiguous".  Prefix `ordem` with either `c1.` or `c2.`, depending on which table's `ordem` column you want to sort by.

Comment: This is a correct answer! Just try goo on "Column in order clause is ambiguous". Ambiguous is means "Hey, you have in all of your tables two columns with same name! Which one did you means realy?"